# How to align subfigures in this specific grid?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to place the bottom right figure in the same way as the bottom left figure but I find it really really difficult. Any ideas?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{./Figures/10026cropped.jpg} &   \includegraphics[width=35mm]{./Figures/10026cropped.jpg} &  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{./Figures/10026cropped.jpg} & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{./Figures/10026cropped.jpg} } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{./Figures/10026cropped.jpg}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The figure]

Comment: I added an explanation on what happened here that I think is interesting not as a solution but on realizing what happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `tabular` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image}\\[2ex]
\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image}

\caption{caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (Programming is fun but sometimes makes you too think very strange things and to feel silly after realizing what you are trying to do).

1. **First step...**

   Ok, I have 5 figures and I need 3 on top and two on bottom, I want to control their placement... A tabular seems a good solution to me...

Let's think:

Three on top: `{ccc}`
First row normal centered and I will split cells via `\multicolumn` in second to share the space... But...

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\include..&\include..&\include..\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}&\multicolumn{2}{c}
\end{tabular}
```

Oh! writing the second `\multicolumn` I realized that they became 4 columns...
Don't even compiling...

Seems I need a fourth column:

Let's try:

2. **Second step...** four columns:

I will split the top middle columns with `\multicolumn`:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\include...&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include...}&\include...\\ %Nice... Let's finish with the next row
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include...}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include}
\end{tabular}
```

4 in the up row 4 in the next... perfect! Let's compile

[image]

Seems I didn't count correct... Lets count...

- Above row 4 cells middle 2 merged
- Below row 2 & 2 cells...

Why first cell of second row doesn't merge with the second? This should give the fourth figure centered in two first columns like fifth... Why?

Do I need to add a fifth column?

Lets see:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
1&2&3&4\\
\include...&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include...}&\include...\\ %Nice... Let's finish with the next row
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include...}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\include}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Fourth image stops before 2nd column... Lets think... Do I need 5 columns?

3. **Third step...** Let's see the vertical lines there? before reporting a bug... But I should!

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
1&2&3&4\\
  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}} &  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-c} \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

They need the bug report... But...

Ok... I think I got it:

The second column has no the width of the third... Of course... No width needed there... Lets add a width:

... Ok I will add centered 17.5mm in both the middle columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}|c|}
  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}} &  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-c} \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Why me???** Let's ask at stackexchange... I am out of here!

4. **No more steps: Some explanation:**

Let's add the 1&2&3&4 row back there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}|c|}
1&2&3&4\\
  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}} &  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-c} \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perfect... But what happened?

LaTeX used just 3 columns since the maximum of the cells needed there was 3 per row... So, the first column was a single column and not really a multicolumn... By adding these help numbers... we are actually lucky and found out what happened... So, adding a full row with empty cells (but all the cells) can solve the problem... Then remove the extra vertical space of the line with `[-1em]` ... Also, with some simple thoughts the second row cells should not be centered because of the extra width of the first and last column... May be `r` and `l` is a better choice ... and a `\tabcolsep` fixed width would help... same distance too (as `\tabcolsep` between rows) and:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{17.5mm}c}
&&&\\[-1em]
  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}} &  \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-c} \\[1mm]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**But why didn't made it in a simpler tabular (of 3 columns)?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}& \includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}&\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-c}\\[1mm]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-a}\hspace{2mm}\includegraphics[width=35mm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Nice... Clever!

But [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479846/120578) is more clever!!! At least I found the problem!

> PS:My answer is because I think that the OPs problem could be happen to anyone and I think that may offer to someone with similar problems even if (of course) some hours (after relaxing) (s)he should think in a simpler way!